# I want to call MASM functions with Inline or macro

Tags: visual-studio, inline-assembly, masm64

I would like to be able to Inline MASM Functions in C code like this:

```
<myfunction.asm> 
myfunction macro
    ...
myfunction endm

<main.c>
int main()
{
   myfunction;
}
```

can call it using extern "C"
but then MyFunction will be called in many places with one Address.
I want to embed new code like a macro where MyFunction is called.
Is this possible?

Comment: Macros are something the assembler uses when generating output code.  But if the macro is never invoked (ie if there aren't any routines in myfunction.asm that use it), there's nothing to call.